# php error Duplicate entry '0' for key 1 at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

php error Duplicate entry '0' for key 1 at line 1

```
include ("connect.php");
include ("register.php");

$urlIdd = isset($_POST['$urlId']);
$urlnamee = isset($_POST['$urlname']);
$dateofurll = isset($_POST['$dateofurl']);  

$createe = mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE 'urls' 
                        ( 'urlId' INT(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                          'urlname' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
                          'dateofurl' DATETIME NOT NULL"
                       ); 

$insertt=mysql_query("INSERT INTO urls (urlId, urlname, dateofurl) 
                      VALUES ('$urlId', '$urlname', '$dateofurl')");
if(!$insertt){
   echo mysql_error();
} else 
   echo "a row has been created successfully";



$updatee = mysql_query("UPDATE urls SET(urlId, urlname, dateofurl) 
                        VALUES ('$urlId', '$urlname', '$dateofurl')");

if(!$updatee){
   echo mysql_error();
} else 
   echo "a row has been changed successfully";

$deletee = mysql_query("DELETE FROM urls 
                        SET(urlId, urlname, dateofurl) 
                        VALUES ('$urlId', '$urlname', '$dateofurl')");
```

Comment: Could you tell us what your question is?

Comment: Post your table structure

Comment: This is mysql error, not PHP, that means your are trying to add a duplicate value for a `PRIMARY KEY` column

Answer (score 1):

This is mysql error, not PHP, that means your are trying to add a duplicate value for a PRIMARY KEY column

As I can see this line in your code

```
$createe = mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'urls' 
                        ( 'urlId' INT(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                          'urlname' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
                          'dateofurl' DATETIME NOT NULL"
                       );
```

Note: use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` because it is more likely your script will be executed more than once, and if TABLE is already created, your script won't produce any error

Your `urlId` is your `PRIMARY KEY` and is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, that means when INSERTing data, you do not need to enter its values, it will be incremented automatically when inserting a new row.

My suggestion is to remove urlid from your query and make it like so, by doing this, value of `urlid` will be Automatically inserted

```
$insertt=mysql_query("INSERT INTO urls ( urlname, dateofurl) 
                      VALUES ( '$urlname', '$dateofurl')");
```

Answer (score -1):

have u tried not to specify your urlID ? it's has an auto increment ..

queries shud be like this

```
$insertt=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `urls` (`urlname`, `dateofurl`) VALUES ('$urlname', '$dateofurl')");

$updatee=mysql_query("UPDATE `urls` SET `urlname`='$urlname' , `dateofurl`='$dateofurl' WHERE `urlId`=$urlId");

$deletee= mysql_query("DELETE from `urls` WHERE `urlId`=$urlId");
```

Comment: post is as comment ... not as answer

Comment: @umair , why so impatient ?